# A better way to sort array by regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
arr = ["/Users/user/Documents/public/170/41/texts/10.txt",
        "/Users/user/Documents/public/170/41/texts/11.txt",
        "/Users/user/Documents/public/170/41/texts/12.txt",
        "/Users/user/Documents/public/170/41/texts/14.txt",
        "/Users/user/Documents/public/170/41/texts/15.txt",
        "/Users/user/Documents/public/170/41/texts/18.txt",
        "/Users/user/Documents/public/170/41/texts/6.txt",
        "/Users/user/Documents/public/170/41/texts/8.txt"]
```

I want to sort it by integer values of .txt files. I am doing this:

```
arr.sort_by{|h| h.scan(/(\d+)\.txt/).flatten[0].to_i}
```

I wonder - is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-basename) instead of parsing the paths yourself:

```
arr.sort_by { |path| File.basename(path, '.txt').to_i }
```

This yields a significant improvement in performance (with an `arr` of size 20,000):

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm(12) do |x|
    x.report("regex: ") { arr.sort_by { |h| h.scan(/(\d+)\.txt/).flatten[0].to_i } }
    x.report("basename: ") { arr.sort_by { |path| File.basename(path, '.txt').to_i } }
end

#                   user     system      total        real
# regex:        0.170000   0.010000   0.180000 (  0.169097)
# basename:     0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.022535)
```

Comment: This answers the question, but it seems as though it only works form files using the `N.txt` naming. It does not, however, handle the general case with numbers anywhere in the file names and paths.

Comment: @Lindydancer It wasn't intended to as neither did the OP's original code.